# Semantic equivalence of XML documents

Tags: xml, xsd, semantics

Let's say I have these two simple XML files:

**Example 1**

```
<parent name="Bob" gender="male">
    <child name="Steve" gender="male"></child>
    <child name="Stephanie" gender="female"></child>
</parent>
```

**Example 2**

```
<parent name="Bob" gender="male">
    <child name="Stephanie" gender="female"></child>

    <child name="Steve" gender="male"></child>

</parent>
```

I am trying to create a function that will input two strings that represent XML and return true if and only if they are semantically equivalent. In this case, even though there are whitespace differences and the order of the children are different, the XML files are still semantically identical.

I currently have a seemingly working solution but I'm afraid it may have drawbacks or I may have overthought the issue. My current solution involves three steps.

1. Remove all whitespace from the strings
2. Sort the strings alphanumerically
3. Perform a standard string equality check

This solution seems to work but I'm wondering if there are any problems with it or if I should be tackling this issue another way.

Comment: Why not just parse the XML using any of the available libraries and checking the extracted values?

Comment: @SJuan76 Can I have some more context please.

Answer (score 2):

**XML has no intrinsic semantics.**  Semantics generally refers to *meaning*, and as a data format, XML itself is not concerned with meaning.

What you really appear to seek is a form of equivalence between two XML documents.   To be able to apply the sort of "standard string equality check" you mention, consider putting the XML into a standard **lexical** form such as is defined by one of the following recommendations:

- [Canonical XML, Version 1.0, W3C Recommendation 15 March 2001](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n)
- [XML Normalization, W3C Editor's Draft 15 March 2013](https://www.w3.org/2008/xmlsec/Drafts/xml-norm/)

Finally, you might consider two documents to be equivalent at a **grammatical** rather than a lexical level by defining equivalence to be true if the documents are both valid according to the same XML schema.

Comment: I don't think normalization orders the elements. For example, the two child tags steve and stephanie, their order shouldnt matter. I just tried normalization but it did not work.

Comment: Element order is significant in XML by default.  Perhaps you'd prefer to specify equivalence at the grammatical level instead where you might indicate order indifference via `xsd:all`.

Comment: Complying with the same schema does not prove grammatical equivalence. Far from it.

Comment: Never said complying with a schema *guarantees* grammatical equivalence.  **Only offered it as a means of making statements regarding a *particular* definition of equivalence at the grammatical level.**  Control over an equivalence class aligned with common validity is just a possibility, not a guarantee to meet any sort of universal notion of equivalence.

Answer (score 1):

What's significant in the XML is something that only you can decide. Steve and Stephen might or might not be the same name. Better not to use the word "semantics": just define what your equivalence rules are. Your general approach to testing equivalence is to define a normal form, transform data into the normal form, and then do a simple lexical test of the normalized values - and that's a perfectly reasonable way of going about it. But only you can decide what the appropriate normalization function is.

Comment: Thank you that is very helpful. I was thinking of traversing the XML document in a breadth-first manner and add all of the nodes to a Set. Then I can check equality of the two sets. I think that will work.

Answer (score 0):

I have a project I wrote based on work from @eric-white [Eric White](https://stackoverflow.com/users/660010/eric%E2%80%91white) formerly from Microsoft.  I just have to dust it off, probably make some updates, and post it to GitHub here: https://github.com/udlose/xml-equivalency

I will update this post once the code has been posted.